# Stripe redirectToCheckout error. Will not load stripe checkout when I click the button to submit

Tags: node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments, checkout

So I've set everything up with stripe to load when I hit submit in my checkout page in react however, I only seem to get this error below. On the stripe dashboard I can see that the POST request is status 200 and the email I am using along with price from the basket etc is reaching stripe. I just don't seem to have the checkout loading. I have compared my code with a guide I'm using and it matches word for word, is it because it's a different version, or am I missing something?

**This is the error I am getting.**

```
Uncaught (in promise) IntegrationError: stripe.redirectToCheckout: You must provide one of lineItems, items, or sessionId.
at v (v3:1)
at g (v3:1)
at j (v3:1)
at t.a (v3:1)
at u (v3:1)
at e.redirectToCheckout (v3:1)
at handleGuestCheckout (stripe-checkout.jsx:32)
```

**This is the checkout.js server file**

```
async function createCheckoutSession(req, res) {
    const domainUrl = process.env.WEB_APP_URL;
    const { line_items, customer_email } = req.body;
    // check req body has line items and email
    if (!line_items || !customer_email) {
        return res.status(400).json({ error: 'missing required session parameters' });
    }

    let session;

    try {
        session = await stripeAPI.checkout.sessions.create({
            payment_method_types: ['card'],
            mode: 'payment',
            line_items,
            customer_email,
            success_url: `${domainUrl}/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`,
            cancel_url: `${domainUrl}/canceled`,
            shipping_address_collection: { allowed_countries: ['GB', 'US'] }
        });
        res.status(200).json({ sessionID: session.id,});
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(400).json({ error: 'an error occured, unable to create session' });
    }
}

module.exports = createCheckoutSession;
```

**And this is the stripe-checkout.jsx file in react**

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from 'react';
import { useStripe } from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';
import { CartContext } from '../../../context/cart-context';
import { fetchFromAPI } from '../../../helpers';

const StripeCheckout = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const { cartItems } = useContext(CartContext);
  const stripe = useStripe();
  const handleGuestCheckout = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const line_items = cartItems.map(item => {
      return {
        quantity: item.quantity,
        price_data: {
          currency: 'usd',
          unit_amount: item.price * 100, // amount is in cents
          product_data: {
            name: item.title,
            description: item.description,
            images: [item.imageUrl], 
          }
        }
      }
    });

    const response = await fetchFromAPI('create-checkout-session', {
      body: { line_items, customer_email: email },
    });

    const { sessionId } = response;
    const { error } = await stripe.redirectToCheckout({
      sessionId
    });
    
    if (error) {
      console.log('error');
    }
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleGuestCheckout}>
      <div>
        <input 
          type='email'
          onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}
          placeholder='Email'
          value={email}
          className='nomad-input'
        />
      </div>
      <div className='submit-btn'>
        <button type='submit' className='button is-black nomad-btn submit'>
          Checkout
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}

export default StripeCheckout;
```

Answer (score 2):

The `redirectToCheckout` call expects you to pass in an object with a key of `sessionId` and the session ID as its value. In your code that would look like:

```
const { error } = await stripe.redirectToCheckout({
  sessionId: sessionId
});
```

Also consider that you can also use the Checkout Session's `url` property. Either with a server side redirect:

```
res.redirect(303, session.url);
```

Or you can send the url back and redirect as you would for any other url:

```
window.location.replace(session_url)
```

Comment: Hey this didn't work but it did get me looking in the right direction, on the backend checkout.js - there was a mistake that didn't match up with the front end

        res.status(200).json({ sessionID: session.id,});

It should have been sessionId  and not sessionID.